# Cypress.io Identity Server

Tags: reactjs, identityserver4, cypress

We have a React application protected by a separate Identity Server site. When unauthenticated, the user is redirected to the login page within Identity Server and then on successful login they are then redirected to a callback URL within the React application.

I'm trying to automate this process as much as possible to improve the speed and reliability of our Cypress.io tests so that we don't need to login via the UI each time - allowing the tests to be atomic and free of unnecessary complexity.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I've followed the examples the Cypress team give around logging in, but haven't been able to get it close to optimal:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on

The closest I've come so far is by following this Auth0 article, but fell short of populating the id_token, nonce and state values to pass to the callback URL:
https://auth0.com/blog/end-to-end-testing-with-cypress-and-auth0/

Any direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tough one that mate!  Could you just grab the bearer token using the identity server request password token endpoint?  Then inject it into the app, bypassing the oidc client?

Comment: I can get the access token no problem so if there's a way to do as you suggest then that's prefect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get around this by hitting the `/connect/token` endpoint of the Identity Server:

```
POST /connect/token 

    client_id=client1&
    client_secret=secret&
    grant_type=password&
    username=username&
    password=password&
    scope=openid profile <client_scope>
```

And then used the response to add an item into session storage:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("oidc:<auth_url>:<client_id>", JSON.stringify(response));
```

Comment: Can you share your full code here, replace your credentials with placeholders, I gotta see your implementation... I am facing the same scenario, where thro' Cypress I have to login into Laravel web app which is authenticated thro' Identity4 auth and then continue with inner pages' tests....